# Exact match in Find and Replace script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm running into a problem with this script where it's replacing all text. [See here](https://i.imgur.com/QKLf4nM.png). The text inside the cells is either =#ERROR! or =#NAME? and the error is coming back as Unknown range name. How can I get it to only replace the specific string of text? Just T, A, R, etc. and not *every* word that contains those letters.

```
function runReplaceInSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Underlevel");
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  //  Fewer calls to access the sheet -> lower overhead 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var replaceObj = {
  //to_replace: imgur id
  T: 'Dxl893F',
  A: 'omc7F9l',
  R: '12ZmSp3',
  M: 'kh7RqBD',
  H: 'u0O7fsS',
  F: 'Hbs3TuP',
};
var regex = new RegExp('^(' + Object.keys(replaceObj).join('|') + ')$', 'g');// /^(T|A|R|M|H|F)$/
function replacer(match) {
  return '=image("https://i.imgur.com/' + replaceObj[match] + '.png")';
}
var data = range.getValues();
range.setFormulas(
  range.getFormulas().map(function(e, i) {//i=index of row(e)
    return e.map(function(f, j) {//j = index of column(f)
      return f === "" ? data[i][j].toString().replace(regex, replacer) : f;
    });
  })
);
}
```

@Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for youre response. I think that in your case, I try to propose to retrieve the data range you want using [``getRange()``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns) instead of ``getDataRange()``. But unfortunately, from your shared image, the range cannot be confirmed. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. If you cannot share the sample Spreadsheet, can you try to modify above?

Comment: In case those images are limited to a certain number of rows and columns, I would design a range (from 1:48 to 17:50 in this case, or the range you need) and iterate  only through the cells in this range.